# Remove href functionality to a specific category menu in magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I'm using magento 1.9.1.0. I would like to disable the href functionality of a specific category menu specially if it has a sub category under it. It will only serve as a normal text when hover and will not jump to another page when clicked. I followed this [tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19601/how-to-remove-an-specific-href-from-a-top-menu-link-in-magento) but no luck. 
Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
Late Update
```

I am using web and people responsive menu extensions.

I created a folder in     app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block and copied the Navigation.php from     app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block. I updated this code

from

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
$html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';
```

to

```
if($category->getLevel()== 2 && $hasActiveChildren) {
            $html[] = '<a href="[removed]void(0);"'.$linkClass.'>';
            $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) .     '</span>';
            $html[] = '</a>';
} else {
            $html[] = '<a href="'.$this-    >getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
            $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) .     '</span>';
            $html[] = '</a>';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry for my late update. I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of jQuery,

If your HTML looks like :

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <a href="link">Title</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
         <li><a href="link">submenu item</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- many such items are there -->
<ul>
```

Then

```
$(function() {
      $(".menu li").each(function() {
          // if any elements are present
          if($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
             $(this).children("a").removeAttr("href");
          }
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me, I just change the appropriate class name and it works. However I am using web and people responsive menu extension and it is not using ul li so I have to disable it in order to disable the href functionality. How can I mange to remove the href functionality if i am using that extension?